# Variables not getting assigned in Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, variables, recursion, assign

I have a piece of code to search for all .txt and .csv files in the a bunch of submit folders inside a main folder.

```
#Folder to check for files
$path="\\Myfolder-DEV\RI*"
#variable which contains the number of files to be processed
$NumOfFiles = 0
            Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | % {
            if (($_.Attributes -eq "Directory") -and ($_.FullName -match "submit")) {
            $myPath = $_.FullName -replace "\\", "/"
                Write-Host $myPath;
                $fileEntries =  Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -include *.txt, *.csv -recurse;
                    foreach($fileName in $fileEntries){ 
                     $myDfile = $fileName.FullName -replace "\\", "/"
                     Write-Host $myDfile;
                     $myOfile = $myDfile -replace '\.[^.\\/]+$'
                     Write-Host $myOfile;
                     $NumOfFiles = $NumOfFiles + 1
                    }
            }
            }
echo "`n$NumOfFiles files were processed`n"
```

When I run this code in DEV, it works fine but when I do it in QA by modifying the path like this, it is not going through the folders at all.

$path="\\Myfolder-QA\RI*"

It even fails to write a value to the variable here
Write-Host $myPath;

I've tried modifying the scope - Clearing the variables at the end of the previous script. Restarting ISE but nothing seems to work.

**Edit:**
When I change the main directory to $path="\\Myfolder-QA\", it seems to work but it is searching through folders that I don't want it to. I need to search through only those folders which start with a RI and it doesnt seem to work. Any idea why it could happen?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: Odd. I'd start with the following steps 1) Does the folder \\Myfolder-QA\RI exist? 2) Does your process have rights to access that folder 3) is the -match "submit" valid for that folder? 4) Start breaking down your script and checking values at each level - i.e. write-host $_.FullName - Does this return a value? etc

Comment: You only have one backslash in your "\MyFolder-QA\RI*", is that the problem?  Does it work if you do $path="\\MyFolder-QA\RI*"

Comment: The code is not entering the Recurse loop at all to search for the ChildItems. It is absolutely driving me crazy. 


The missing backslash was a type. It actually is present :)

Comment: I figured out the issue - The problem seems to be with the RI Wildcard. It seems to not go into the loop when I specify RI*

When I keep the directory as $path="\\Myfolder-QA\" it is working but I really need to exclude all the directories which dont start with RI. Any ideas?